# Lasso Regression: The continuous heavy step function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lasso-regression

From many documents, I have learned the recipe of Ridge regression that is:

```
loss_Ridge = loss_function + lambda x L2 norm of slope
```

and the recipe of Lasso regression that is:

```
loss_Lasso = loss_function + lambda x L1 norm of slope
```

When I have read topic "Implementing Lasso and Ridge Regression" in "[TensorFlow Machine Learning Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HY3TC54)", its author explained that:

> "...we will use a continuous approximation to a step function, called
>   the continuous heavy step function..."

and its author also provided lines of code [here](https://github.com/TranNgocMinh/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/03_Linear_Regression/06_Implementing_Lasso_and_Ridge_Regression/06_lasso_and_ridge_regression.py).
I don't understand about which is called '**the continuous heavy step function**' in this context. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link that you provided,

```
if regression_type == 'LASSO':
    # Declare Lasso loss function
    # Lasso Loss = L2_Loss + heavyside_step,
    # Where heavyside_step ~ 0 if A < constant, otherwise ~ 99
    lasso_param = tf.constant(0.9)
    heavyside_step = tf.truediv(1., tf.add(1., tf.exp(tf.multiply(-50., tf.subtract(A, lasso_param)))))
    regularization_param = tf.multiply(heavyside_step, 99.)
loss = tf.add(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_target - model_output)), regularization_param)
```

This `heavyside_step` function is very close to a logistic function which in turn can be a continuous approximation for a step function.

You use continuous approximation because the loss function needs to be differentiable with respect to the parameters of your model.

To get an intuition about read the constrained formulation section 1.6 in https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Documents/2005_Notes_Lasso.pdf

You can see that in your code if A < 0.9 then regularization_param vanishes, so optimization will constrain A in that range.

Comment: Can you provide a document which describes this function (heavy step function) in detail? I have read code above but I want to understand about how to use this function in the context which relates to Lasso.

Comment: Thank @dgumo. I read your document but i still didn't understand about recipe of heavyside_step. I am trying to refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function and i hope i will find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize features using Lasso Regression here you have one example:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
estimator = Lasso()
featureSelection = SelectFromModel(estimator)
featureSelection.fit(features_vector, target)
selectedFeatures = featureSelection.transform(features_vector)
print(selectedFeatures)
```